# Elements <tr> are not scaling to the container

Tags: css, flexbox, less

I want to create a table using `flexbox`. The problem is columns are not scaling to the 100% of the container - in fact `table`, `thead` and `tbody` are in correct size, but `tr`s are not.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td><input placeholder="Filter" /></td>
            <td><input placeholder="Filter" /></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

LESS:

```
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 200px;

  thead, tbody {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJdqEe)

Comment: So why do you use `table` elements?

Comment: There is no need to use Flex if you are using <table> elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the cells does not align is because you added `display: flex` to the `table` and both it and the `thead`/`tbody` stopped behave as just that.

Each group of `tr` (in the `thead` and `tbody`), which no longer has a normal shared `table` as a direct parent, will size by their content.

Their might even be an anonymous table created, which even better would describe the issue, but can't say that for sure, so if someone knows that, feel free to comment or update my answer.

By adding these 2 rules, it will start work similar to a table.

```
tbody tr, thead tr {
  display: flex;
}
tbody td, thead td {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwPjxX)

---

May I recommend you use the `table` elements as is, or if you want Flexbox, do like this instead, using i.e. `div` elements.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwPogz)

Stack snippet

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}
.table .scroller {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}
.table .scroller .row {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.table .row {
  display: flex;
}
.table .row > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div>Header 1</div>
    <div>Header 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div><input placeholder="Filter" /></div>
    <div><input placeholder="Filter" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>123</div>
      <div>456</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```